# PyQt TableView align Icons to Center

Tags: python, pyqt, qtableview

I have a QTableView with icons and these icons by default display aligned to the left while I want to align them to the center. From the Qt Documentation the alignment only occurs for the TextAlignment under Qt.role only which has the role of Qt.DisplayRole().

How can the alingment be set to center for icons which have Qt.DecorationRole().

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to use a delegate:

```
class IconDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super().initStyleOption(option, index)
        option.decorationSize = option.rect.size()
```

```
delegate = IconDelegate(tableview)
tableview.setItemDelegate(delegate)
```

Comment: For anyone not understanding this accepted answwer.  = option.rect.size() does centre the icon but if you need to resize the icon e.g. option.decorationSize = QSize(16, 16) then the centering is lost.   Adding option.decorationAlignment = Qt.AlignHCenter does not bring it back to the centre.    Personally there is a lack of explanation in this accepted answer.

Comment: @ByteInsight While further explanations would certainly improve it, it *does* answer the main problem, since it's based on the default behavior, which always uses icon sizes following the style or the view's `iconSize()`. If you want a different icon size specific for each item, then it's a slightly different question. Otherwise, just use `tableView.setIconSize()`.