# Pyside6 QAbstractTableModel - Replace Boolean value with centre aligned icon

Tags: python, pyside, qabstracttablemodel

I have a class *GenericTableModel(QAbstractTableModel):* in which I am trying to replace Boolean *<class 'numpy.bool_'>* with icons.  I have had it working using the following:

```
if role == Qt.DecorationRole:
    value = self.dataframe.iloc[index.row(), index.column()]
    if hasattr(value, 'dtype') and value.dtype == bool:
        if value:
            return QIcon('static/icons/check-circle-fill.png')
        return QIcon("static/icons/icon_x.png")
```

But they were left aligned and I'd like them centred.

If I change the role to QDisplayRole then no icons are displayed because the value type at this time is always str.  I guess this is because I am misunderstanding the role.

I have added the following from [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63177587/pyqt-tableview-align-icons-to-center/63178044#63178044) and been able to set the icon size but not the alignment as it is not clearly specified in the answer given.

```
class IconDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
    super().initStyleOption(option, index)
    option.decorationSize = QSize(16, 16) # option.rect.size()
```

Looking at the docs I'm expecting maybe a displayAlignment or textAlignment but they don't appear to be valid.

I suspect its based on a two prong misundertanding.   I think DecorationRole is always intended to decorate the left side of a cell and if I can get the right role it might work?

Anyway, if someone could offer me some assistance I'd be grateful. Thanks

Comment: The only way to properly center the icon is to override the `paint()` of the delegate and draw it on your own.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63178044/6622587

Comment: @eyllanesc  Where in the link above does it show how to actually align the icon.  If you had read the question you would have seen I have used this code but am still at a loss how to centre from there.